# Operation not permitted when trying to read process memory

Tags: linux, memory, coredump

I am trying to read the process memory from the `/proc/<pid>/mem` when the process is creating the core dump (this is handled within a bash script that is called from the core_pattern).

When the process is running I can run the script and read the memory but when it's been called from the core_pattern then I get an error "Operation not permitted".

I tried using "PTRACE_ATTACH" but that made no difference.

Is there anything I should do to allow me to read while creating the core dump?

Comment: *"I am trying to read"* please show what you are trying. Otherwise, we cannot really help you.

Comment: I tried to use the minicoredump application but when it didn't work I took a simple python script to see where I fail. The script opens the /proc/pid/mem (this does not fail) and then I try to read a chunk of the file (for testing I tried to read on 10 bytes) I get the "Operation not permitted".

Comment: *This is the script* - please **show** the script or even better, include a [**minimal, verifyable and complete example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier to help you.

Comment: i used the python code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483984/python-read-linux-memory-process-error-proc-pid-mem